# Sending mail through DB or through service call from a CLR

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, email

I've a scenario where I've to send a mail after checking a condition after every insert in a table.

- Is trigger the right way to do it?

My second question would be as to what approach to take

- Should I directly send a mail from the DB. (Note: My DBserver and Mail server are in different networks, might've to create  firewall rule exception)
- Should I have a CLR-sproc. From the DB, I call the CLR-sproc and CLR-sproc calls a service and from there sends the mail.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both SQL Server DBMail and a CLR proc will use SMTP to send the email. So, why add complexity?

In addition, sending an email via DBMail or CLR will require processing on INSERT. Note that DBMail uses a queue so will impact less than running a CLR procedure.

A trigger is a good way to do it. However, consider using a stored procedure to do the ISNERT with the email sent outside of the transaction (you'll have an implicit one because of the INSERT). Sending in a trigger means it is *part* of the implicit transaction for the INSERT.

From a security perspective, SQLMachine still needs access to SMTPMachine, whether using DBMail or a service call by a CLR Proc.

Comment: Through the CLR-proc, I'm planning to asynchronously calling a web service which will take care of sending the mail. I believe I cant directly call a web service from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, a trigger would be the right way of performing an action after every insert

2) SQL server has a feature called [Database Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175887%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) which looks like it will do what you want (although I've never used it myself)

Comment: Using Database mail would be a problem because the Mail server would be in a different machine and we might get problems from the security guys.

Comment: From what I've read having the mail server on a different machine isn't a (technical) problem. DBMail doesn't actually send the mail, it just manages sending messages through the mail server you specify. There would be no practical difference between using it, or using a CLR sproc to do it yourself.